# Query with count( (array) $test) > 1 as parameters

Tags: php, mysql

I do have a table - we call the table attributes:

id  | color | size

1   | red   | L

2   | red   | XL

3   | blue  | L

4   | blue  | XL
...

Now I have an array that looks like this:

```
$parameters[0] = array('red', 'L');
$parameters[1] = array('red', 'XL');
$parameters[2] = array('blue', 'L');
```

How does my query in RAW-SQL has to look like, if I want to have the result to be like this:

```
$result = array(1,2,3);
```

Comment: what is your query please show us because we don't know how you passed parameter?

Comment: I just don't know how to do that at all? Is there a better way than to do an foreach loop?

Comment: Crap, little mistake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using PDO something like this should work.

```
$parameters[0] = array('red', 'L');
$parameters[1] = array('red', 'XL');
$parameters[2] = array('blue', 'L');
$where = '';
foreach($parameters as $param) {
     $where[] = '(color = ?  and size = ?)';
     $params[] = $param[0];
     $params[] = $param[1];
 }
$where = implode(' or ', $where);
```

append the `$where` to your query then use the `$params` with the `execute`.

Demo: https://eval.in/801247

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id FROM attributes
WHERE (color = 'red' AND size = 'L') 
      OR (color = 'red' AND size = 'XL') 
      OR (color = 'blue' AND size = 'L');
```

RAW-SQL for your problem. Now you can make php implementation as your need!